# Flutter Firebase.signInWithGoogle method not found

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add Google Authentication in my Flutter Application. But my Android studio is not able to find the method **signInWithGoogle** under **FirebaseAuth** class. I mean to say when I write FirebaseAuth.**signInWithGoogle** Android studio complains saying **The method signInWithGoogle isn't defined for the class Firebase**.

I already have the have **Firebase.signInWithEmailAndPassword** and it is working fine.

I have below dependency in pubspec.yaml
firebase_auth: ^0.8.0+1

Below are my imports in the class...

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:my_project/auth.dart';
import 'package:my_project/register.dart';
import 'package:my_project/signin/button_list.dart';
import 'package:my_project/signin/button_view.dart';
import 'package:my_project/utils.dart';
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
 final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

// Google Sign In
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; // No errors so far
```

below is the method in the same class that shows the error
[image]

Also when I click the ctrl + space to see all the methods under **FirebaseAuth** it is not showing the **signInWithGoogle** method at all.

[image]

please help!
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Did you follow all of the [steps](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth)? Make sure you’ve a `FirebaseAuth.instance`

Comment: Yes. Actually I already have login with email and password in Firebase.

Comment: Your imports seem ok. Must be something else. Can you edit with the full code?

Comment: check out the example provided in the firebase_auth github repo 
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/example/lib/main.dart#L70

Comment: @Harshapulikollu I will try it today and will update the post. thanks for your time and help

Comment: Thank you @Harshapulikollu it resolved my issue

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

check out the example provided in the firebase_auth github repo
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/example/lib/main.dart#L70

```
Future<String> _testSignInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
    assert(user.email != null);
    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}
```

Comment: I think something must have changed since then because nowadays `_auth.signInWithCredential(credential)` gives back `AuthResult` not `FirebaseUser`. In order to access the user, use `(await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user`.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the accepted answer, since firebase_auth version 0.12.0:

> Sign-in methods now return AuthResult instead of FirebaseUser.
>   Retrieve the FirebaseUser using the user property of AuthResult.

So the actual correct solution is:

```
...
    final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using fireebaseauth.signInWithGoogle (which is depreciated)
use:

```
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken
);
```

Your code will look like this:

```
Future handleSign() async {
preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
setState(() {
  loading = true;
});

GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleUser
    .authentication;
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);
}
```