# Firebase Authentification can't use google sign-in in my flutter app

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I've had firebase-auth an google-signin in my flutter app, when in tap on my button "Signin with Google", a google pop-up opens so that i can choose the google account i want to use, when I tap on my account, the pop-up close, and I've this in my console :

```
D/ViewRootImpl@8929a4d[SignInHubActivity](25903): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
V/InputMethodManager(25903): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@c535c6f nm : com.youpa.youpa ic=null
D/InputMethodManager(25903): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(25903): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport(25903): Input channel constructed: fd=101
D/ViewRootImpl@8929a4d[SignInHubActivity](25903): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
I/flutter (25903): Error : ** firebase_error.sign_in_failed not found
D/ViewRootImpl@b0e6bd3[MainActivity](25903): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
V/InputMethodManager(25903): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@2825d7c nm : com.youpa.youpa ic=null
D/InputMethodManager(25903): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(25903): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport(25903): Input channel constructed: fd=110
D/InputTransport(25903): Input channel destroyed: fd=101
D/OpenGLRenderer(25903): eglDestroySurface = 0xbbbe7e60, 0xc1571800
D/ViewRootImpl@8929a4d[SignInHubActivity](25903): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1280] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
D/ViewRootImpl@8929a4d[SignInHubActivity](25903): dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputEventReceiver(25903): channel '5a554e2 com.youpa.youpa/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity (client)' ~ Disposing input event receiver.
D/InputEventReceiver(25903): channel '5a554e2 com.youpa.youpa/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity (client)' ~NativeInputEventReceiver.
D/InputTransport(25903): Input channel destroyed: fd=97
```

And I'm not logged. However, my firbase auth system with email works perfectly. Here you have the onPressed of my Google Signin button :

```
onPressed: () {
              Auth()
                  .handleSignInWithGoogle()
                  .then((FirebaseUser user) {
              }).catchError((e) {
                print("Error : " +
                    internationalization
                        .text("firebase_error." + e.code));
              });
            },
```

An here, you have some parts of my auth services :

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:youpa/Model/user.model.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'options.services.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class Auth {
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: [
      'email',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
      'profile'
    ],
  );
  final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<FirebaseUser> handleSignInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    FirebaseUser user = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    assert(user.email != null);
    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
    print(user);
    print(currentUser);

    return user;
  }
}
```

Do you see where is the mistake ?
Thank's in advance.
Jérémy.

Comment: similar questioned answer :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54508591/flutter-firebase-signinwithgoogle-method-not-found

Comment: Yes, but my code is the same of the correct anwer of your link. (I've just add print()). Thank's anyway.

Comment: Have you provided the Credentials of SHA1 and SHA256 correctly.

Comment: Also If you have added them after also, have you created the JSON file again and pasted in the app?

Answer (score 0):

Verify if the sign-in method for [Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth#google) on the Firebase Console is enabled. It's likely to be the cause why the error throws a "not found" error. Also, for Android you need to ensure [SHA1 key](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) has been configured in the Firebase project as mentioned in the docs.