# Undefined class 'FirebaseUser'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I'm new to Flutter. I have an Issue with **Firebase Auth/ Google Auth**
The **FirebaseUser** is not defined
Code:

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

Future<FirebaseUser> currentUser() async { // The Issue is here in the Future<>
  final GoogleSignInAccount account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication authentication =
      await account.authentication;

  final GoogleAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      idToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken);

  final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user; // and here as I can't define this FirebaseUser object to return

  return user;
}
```

Pubspec.yml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0
  location: ^3.0.2
  page_transition: ^1.1.6
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.1
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  firebase_database: ^4.0.0
```

I also face the same issue with AuthResult

```
final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

Comment: are you settings at firebase google sign-in method?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to add google sign-in to my app

Answer (score 152, accepted):

### Starting from Version `firebase_auth` 0.18.0:

In the newest version of `firebase_auth`, the class `FirebaseUser` was changed to `User`, and the class `AuthResult` was changed to `UserCredential`. Therefore change your code to the following:

```
    Future<User> currentUser() async {
      final GoogleSignInAccount account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication authentication =
          await account.authentication;

      final GoogleAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          idToken: authentication.idToken,
          accessToken: authentication.accessToken);

      final UserCredential authResult =
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      final User user = authResult.user;

      return user;
    }
```

---

`FirebaseUser` changed to `User`

`AuthResult` changed to `UserCredential`

`GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential()` changed to `GoogleAuthProvider.credential()`

---

`onAuthStateChanged` which notifies about changes to the user's sign-in state was replaced with `authStateChanges()`

`currentUser()` which is a method to retrieve the currently logged in user, was replaced with the property `currentUser` and it no longer returns a `Future<FirebaseUser>`.

Example of the above two methods:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((event) {
   print(event.email);
});
```

And:

```
var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
print(user.uid);
```

---

Deprecation of `UserUpdateInfo` class for `firebaseUser.updateProfile` method.
Example:

```
Future updateName(String name, FirebaseUser user) async {
  var userUpdateInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();
  userUpdateInfo.displayName = name;
  await user.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
  await user.reload(); 
}
```

now

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as firebaseAuth;
Future updateName(String name, auth.User firebaseUser) async {
  firebaseUser.updateProfile(displayName: name);
  await firebaseUser.reload();
}
```

Comment: Well written answer, but I am getting an error when I am trying to log in to the user till he logs out. I request you, can you please answer this question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63933753/getting-error-while-saving-sign-in-google-in-flutter/63933975#63933975) I am stuck here please give me the direction

Comment: Also add deprecation of `UserUpdateInfo`, which is now `firebaseUser.updateProfile`

Comment: Highly impressive answer. Thanks dear :)

Comment: Google has updated code for updating profile's each attribute. eg. If user wants to change display name then code will be like `firebaseUser.updateDisplayName(name);` Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Since `firebase_auth 0.18.0`, the class `FirebaseUser` was changed to `User`

Answer (score 2):

In the newest version of firebase_auth, the class **FirebaseUser** was changed to **User**, and the class **AuthResult** was changed to **UserCredentail**. Therefore change **FirebaseUser** to **User**

Answer (score 2):

**The class FirebaseUser was changed to User**

try this way

```
 _registerUser() async {
    try {
      final User? user =
          (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailCtrl.text,
        password: passCtrl.text,
      ))
              .user;
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc().set({
        'name': nameCtrl.text,
        'uid': user!.uid,
        'email': user.email,
        'isEmailVerified': user.emailVerified, // will also be false
        'photoUrl': user.photoURL, // will always be null
      });
      print("Created");
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be your signin function with email and password as of Sept 2020.Initialze app is a new introduced method we must at least call once before we use any other firebase methods.

```
 Future<void> signin() async {
    final formState = _formkey.currentState;
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    if (formState.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        loading = true;
      });
      formState.save();
      try {
        print(email);
        final User user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password))
            .user;
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.message);
        setState(() {
          loading = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
flutter pub get
```

Then **rebuild** your app.

Comment: This response doesn't explain the source of the problem nor solve it.