# Need help in solving Undefined class FireBaseUser

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

whenever i connect firebase with flutter it gives me this type of error .
undefined class 'FirebaseUser' and also i am not able to check wheteher my firebase is linked with flutter project or not !

```
return FlatButton(
          child: const Text('Sign out'),
          textColor: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
          onPressed: () async {
            final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser;
            if (user == null) {
```

Comment: Change `FirebaseUser` to `User`, thats all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined class 'FirebaseUser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482162/undefined-class-firebaseuser)

Answer (score 0):

What version of the plugin are you using? FirebaseAuth now uses `User` instead of `FirebaseUser`.