# I don't know why the firebase user and the FireStore isn't responding to the static command? Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package: firebase _auth/firebase_auth.dart';


class shocker{
        
  static const String appName = 'Shocker'

  static FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    
  static FireStore FireStore;
    
  static FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the firebase user and the FireStore isn't responding to the static command" ?

Comment: It keeps giving that error line when I implement the FireStore and firebase user with a static

Comment: What does the error line say?

Comment: Undefined class.... Do you have any idea why that is sir???

Comment: Please show the *exact* error, including which line it's referring to. It's really important that whenever you're asking a question about an error, you make the error itself as clear as possible.

Comment: @Jon Skeet... I just did, the FirebaseUser shown there shows undefined class even after I imported the firebase_auth dependency into the dart file

Comment: "the FirebaseUser shown there shows undefined class" - where is that stated in the question? Earlier - but still in comments - you told us that you received an "Undefined class" error message, but with no indication of where or which class is shown as being undefined. *Details matter.*

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482162 for FirebaseUser being a problem. (And note that that was the first result for a query of "undefined class FirebaseUser".)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `FireStore` to `FirebaseFirestore`.

```
  static FireStore FireStore;
```

becomes

```
  static FirebaseFirestore firestore;
```

Check out the Cloud Firestore Usage Documentation: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage