# Receiving warning message for null operator

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I declared _auth and called it in the register button, so it takes me to another screen
but I am receiving a warning that says;

"The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true."

Please help me solve this problem, I really do not understand the problem at all.

```
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; //This is where I declared the auth variable

  late String email;
  late String password;
 
            RoundedButton(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              title: 'Register',
              onPress: () async {
                try {
                  final newUser =
                      await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

                  if (newUser != null) { //This is where the warning comes from
                    if (!mounted) return;
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
                  }
                } catch (e) {
                  print(e);
                }
              },
            ),
```

Comment: I couldn't edit as there is writtern "There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later." Please wrap your code part, to make it easy to read".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the  `await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)` will return an `UserCredential` object, **which it will never be null**, so making an `if else` condition over it doesn't do anything really since the `newUser != null` will always equals to `true`.

the piece of code you wrote is equivalent to this:

```
 final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; //This is where I declared the auth variable
```

late String email;
late String password;

```
        RoundedButton(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          title: 'Register',
          onPress: () async {
            try {
              final newUser =
                  await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

                if (!mounted) return;
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
            
            } catch (e) {
              print(e);
            }
          },
        ),
```

I'm assuming that you want to catch exceptions/erros that might be thrown from this auth operation like an `invalid-email`, `weak-password`, `email-already-in use`, for that you need to catch with the special `Exception` class of Firebase Auth, the `FirebaseAuthException`, so your code should be like this now:

```
  late String email;
  late String password;

        RoundedButton(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          title: 'Register',
          onPress: () async {
            try {
              final newUser =
                  await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

                if (!mounted) return;
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
            
            } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
              print(e.code);
              print(e.message);
            }
          },
        ),
```

now, looking at that line:

```
   final newUser =
              await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
```

create a new user as expected, then it will return the result of that request which is a `UserCredentail` that contains some specific user's information such as email, access token, uid..., so if you created the user account and then save the `UserCredentail` without using it, it will show you a warning (not really an error):

```
The value of the local variable isn’t used In Dart
```

now if we used that variable like this as example:

```
print(newUser);
```

the warning will disappear because it's used now.

if you're not planning to use that variable in your actual project, then you can just call the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` like this:

```
 await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
```

Without saving it in a variable, it will create a new account for the user as expected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh ok thanks... side question by the way... has firebaseUser changed ?

Comment: also the new warning thrown is that the local variable 'newUser' isn't used

Comment: yes it's changed to User, check out that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482162/undefined-class-firebaseuser

Comment: if you will not use it just call the method directly, without saving the return in the newUser variable,

Comment: If you're willing to use it for future, if you wanna get the email..., then just ignore it right now, when you do use it in the future that warning will dissapear

Comment: call the method directly??? I don't follow please... could you illustrate please

Comment: wait I will add it in the answer

Comment: I updated the answer, check it and feel free to give any other questions

Comment: Yeah I have seen it Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249771/discussion-between-fred-wolfe-and-gwhyyy).